# Multiple virtual box and multiple vagrant box possibility

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

Is it possible to install 2 virtual boxes and then each one can have 1-1 vagrant boxes inside it. Problem is one of my project supports vagrant box 1.7 and another one supports 1.9.

Comment: I guess you talk about vagrant 1.7 or 1.9 - virtualbox versions are 4.x or 5.x - while you could probably work with 2 different vagrant versions (you need to make sure symlinks point to right version) I dont think there's a need for this. Just use the same vagrant version for your 2 boxes and you'll be fine

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHenri for the correction. I can try with the symlinks suggestion to see if that can solve my problem. Thanks